# Partial template specialization for variadic types and variadic argument packs expanded into outer type result in ambiguity

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

I'm trying to compile the following program with g++-4.7 (20120228-1):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <tuple>

template<typename X> struct Y {};

template<typename T, size_t Level, size_t TermLevel> struct A;

// (B) dummy for T=tuple<int, Ts...> just to show it works for simple expansions
template<typename ... Ts, size_t Level, size_t TermLevel>
struct A<std::tuple<int, Ts...>, Level, TermLevel>
{
    A<std::tuple<int, Ts...>, Level+1, TermLevel> value;
};

template<typename ... Ts, size_t Level>
struct A<std::tuple<int, Ts...>, Level, Level> {};


// (C) ambiguous partial specialization
template<typename ... Ts, size_t Level, size_t TermLevel>
struct A<std::tuple<Y<Ts>...>, Level, TermLevel>
{
    A<std::tuple<Y<Ts>...>, Level+1, TermLevel> value;
};

template<typename ... Ts, size_t Level>
struct A<std::tuple<Y<Ts>...>, Level, Level> {};


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    A<std::tuple<int, float, int>, 0, 5> tint;
    A<std::tuple<Y<int>, Y<float>>, 0, 1> tn;
    return 0;
}
```

which results in an ambiguity as follows:

```
g++-4.7 -g -O0 -std=c++0x    specialization_orig.cc   -o specialization_orig
specialization_orig.cc: In instantiation of 'struct A<std::tuple<Y<int>, Y<float> >, 0ul, 1ul>':
specialization_orig.cc:33:43:   required from here
specialization_orig.cc:23:49: error: ambiguous class template instantiation for 'struct A<std::tuple<Y<int>, Y<float> >, 1ul, 1ul>'
specialization_orig.cc:21:8: error: candidates are: struct A<std::tuple<Y<Ts>...>, Level, TermLevel>
specialization_orig.cc:27:8: error:                 struct A<std::tuple<Y<Ts>...>, Level, Level>
specialization_orig.cc:23:49: error: 'A<std::tuple<Y<Ts>...>, Level, TermLevel>::value' has incomplete type
specialization_orig.cc:6:61: error: declaration of 'struct A<std::tuple<Y<int>, Y<float> >, 1ul, 1ul>'
```

this is kind of weird since variadic argument expansion works for the simple expansion of the argument pack, but fails as soon as the variadic argument packs is expanded to be nested within some other template type.

Is this simply compiler madness or am i doing anything terribly wrong?

Comment: ICC rejects this code as well with "error: more than one partial specialization matches the template argument list of class "A<std::tuple<Y<int>, Y<float>>, 1UL, 1UL>"

"A<std::tuple<Y<Ts>...>, Level, TermLevel>"

"A<std::tuple<Y<Ts>...>, Level, Level>"

A<std::tuple<Y<Ts>...>, Level+1, TermLevel> value;", but CLang accepts it.  Can anyone with Comeau or a new enough VC++ try this, as I do not have access to VS2013, and the Comeau try-it-out is down?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a GCC bug, because the ambiguity goes away if you replace the parameter pack with a fixed number of parameters: http://ideone.com/6D4Fi .

This sort of ambiguity can also be resolved using `std::enable_if`.

```
/* add "typename = void" anonymous parameter which enables individual partial
   specializations by matching the void result in std::enable_if<>::type. */
template<typename T, size_t Level, size_t TermLevel, typename = void> struct A;

// No enable_if needed here: always enabled if the levels are equal.
template<typename ... Ts, size_t Level>
struct A<std::tuple<int, Ts...>, Level, Level, void> {}; // just pass void

// Use enable_if to disable in case the levels are equal.
template<typename ... Ts, size_t Level, size_t TermLevel>
struct A<std::tuple<Y<Ts>...>, Level, TermLevel,
    typename std::enable_if< Level != TermLevel >::type >
```

Comment: sure, `enable_if` is always an option. Even though i think it should not be necessary in this case. first of all because specializing (C) to `template<typename ... Ts> struct A<std::tuple<Y<Ts>...>, 1, 1> {};` also doesn't help and second because it doesn't complain about (B) which should yield the same ambiguity following your explanation

Comment: @ignatz: Ah, so it is! There must be a rule that functions with fewer template parameters are more specialized if otherwise they would be equally specialized. I don't have time to review right now :v( . Anyway, I would go with `enable_if` because it's an expedient, obvious fix. I think you've just stumbled on a GCC bug. It also goes away if you eliminate the parameter pack: http://ideone.com/6D4Fi